# Opencv c++ capture images from two cameras using two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, thread-safety

I've written this code that grabs the frames from two ip cameras and after it stitches together the two images.
In Init I open the camera, then in grabThread loop I grab the camera frames and I set a mutex.
In getFrame I get the mutex and release the cvMat by reference.

```
class GrabberThread {
private:
    std::string device;
    cv::Mat mm;
    std::atomic<bool> grabOn;
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    std::mutex mtx;
public:
GrabberThread() : grabOn(false) {};
~GrabberThread()
{
    grabOn.store(false);
    cap.release();
}
bool Init(std::string dev)
{
    device = dev;
    cap.open(device);
    std::cout << "cap " << dev << " opened " << cap.isOpened() << "\n";
    return cap.isOpened();
}
void StopGrabing()
{
    grabOn.store(false);
}
void GrabThread()
{
    if (!cap.isOpened()) cap.open(device);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) return;
    cv::Mat tmp;
    grabOn.store(true);
    while (grabOn.load() == true)
    {
        if (!cap.read(tmp))
            continue;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            tmp.copyTo(mm);
        }
    }
} 
void getFrame(cv::Mat& m)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        mm.copyTo(m);
    }
}
};
```

Then i call getFrame from outside the thread to get the images I grabbed.
Until now everything works fine, but is it all right or do I risk some race conditions? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronization around the matrix is fine, however your destructor will likely cause problems. If the dtor is finished before `GrabThread` finishes a loop iteration the life time of all members will be over and accessing them is undefined behavior. You should use a [condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) or some other synchronization facility to ensure that `GrabThread` has finished before your dtor returns.